# WPF DataGridColumn MultiConverter Parameters are UnSetValue

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

My problem is always Converter's second parameter which is `DependencyProperty.UnSetValue`. I cannot fix that. I try many things and suggested solution in similar topics in forums but again I failed. If I use itemscontrol instead of datagrid, there is no any problem and code works but I have to use data grid.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Definitions}" DataContext="{Binding Test}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type definitions:Definition}">
      <Expander Header="{Binding Name}" x:Name="expander" Width="700" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" DataContext="{Binding}" IsExpanded="True">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

          <Grid Grid.Row="0">
          </Grid>

          <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,0">
            <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=expander}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CanUserAddRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
              <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=AutoNamed,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn DisplayMemberPath="ID" SelectedValuePath="Number" Header="-" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=Start,Mode=TwoWay}">
                  <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
                      <Binding Path="Test.Types" Source="{x:Static viewmodels:ApplicationVM.Instance}" />
                      <Binding Path="DataContext.Name" ElementName="expander" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                  </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="+" DisplayMemberPath="ID" SelectedValuePath="Number" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=End,Mode=TwoWay}">
                  <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
                      <Binding Path="Test.Types" Source="{x:Static viewmodels:ApplicationVM.Instance}" />
                      <Binding Path="Header" ElementName="expander" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                  </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Low" Binding="{Binding Path=Low,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="High" Binding="{Binding Path=High,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Auto Name" Binding="{Binding Path=AutoNamed,Mode=TwoWay}" />
              </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Expander>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Firstly, I thought it could be the binding issue. So, I added two new column to test.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name2" Binding="{Binding Path=Header, ElementName=expander}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name3" Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.Name, ElementName=expander}"/>
```

These two columns worked. I can see it is not binding data issue, but what I send as parameter instead of view model property is `UnSetValue` in Converter. How can it be possible? It is also inherited from `ItemsControl`. I can not bind parent datacontext to datagrid. How can I solve this problem? I am glad to get help about it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `ItemsSource` property of the `ComboBox` in the `ElementStyle` and `EditingElementStyle` of the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`. You can then use a `RelativeSource` to bind to the `Expander`:

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=expander}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                              CanUserAddRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="PlusColumnStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
                        <!--<Binding Path="Test.Types" Source="{x:Static viewmodels:ApplicationVM.Instance}" />-->
                        <Binding Path="Header" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Expander}" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="+" DisplayMemberPath="ID" SelectedValuePath="Number" 
                                                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=End,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                    ElementStyle="{StaticResource PlusColumnStyle}" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource PlusColumnStyle}"/>
        <!-- + the other columns...-->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Don't set the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` itself. This won't work because a `DataGridColumn` is not a visual `UIElement` that gets added to the visual tree so it won't be able to find the `Expander`.

Comment: Hi mm8, I tried your solution. Your answer is also correct. I check and I see Column objects intherit from DependencyObject, it is not UIElement like you said. I didn't know it. Thanks your answer and your help.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is based on [this article](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/). Create a class that inherits Freezable and declares a Data dependency property:

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore() { return new BindingProxy(); }
    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    } 
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), 
            typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

declare an instance of this class as the Expanders resources:

```
<Expander.Resources>
      <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding ElementName=expander}"/>
</Expander.Resources>
```

Note the "ElementName=expander" part. Use it in declaring the Bindings. The following gives the Expander as the first element.

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
      <Binding Source="{StaticResource proxy}"  />
</MultiBinding>
```

Comment: Thanks your help and Ramin, it solve my problem with a little editing. When I define the Proxy in DataGrid resources and I can reach the viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ramin. I solved the problem, but I have to some changes.

According to Artical,
I can bind view-model to proxy like below

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

And after that,

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="+" DisplayMemberPath="ID" SelectedValuePath="Number" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=End,Mode=TwoWay}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
            <Binding Path="Test.Types" Source="{x:Static viewmodels:ApplicationVM.Instance}" />
          <Binding Path="Data.Name" Source="{StaticResource proxy}"  />
         </MultiBinding>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

I can reach my view-model over the proxy, so parameters is not UnSetValue anymore.

Comment: You don't have to use a binding proxy. You just have to set the ElementStyle and EditingElementStyle properties of the DataGridComboBoxColumn properties of the column. See my answer for more information.